# Swap token directly with UniswapV3 pool

Tags: web3.py, uniswapv3, anvil

I've researched previous questions, however it does not seems to work out for me, therefore I am asking. I want to swap WETH to USDT on UniswapV3 directly via the pool of both pairs, not through the router. Fyi the code is in python & web3.
As far as I understood following steps are necessary:

1. Wrap ETH to WETH via WETH9 contract.
2. Approve the pool(WETH/USDT) in the WETH9 to spend a certain amount.
3. Call swap() of the pool with the given [parameters](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolActions#swap).

Below the code, note that I am forking mainnet using anvil.

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_account import Account
from eth_account.signers.local import LocalAccount
from web3.middleware import construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware

import json
with open("UniswapV3Router2.json") as f:
    info_json = json.load(f)
V3_router_abi = info_json
with open("ERC20.json") as f:
    erc20_json = json.load(f)
ERC20_abi = erc20_json
with open("UniswapV3Pool.json") as f:
    poolv3_json = json.load(f)
POOLV3_abi = poolv3_json


w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:8545'))
account: LocalAccount = Account.from_key("0x00")

# add key to middleware to sign transactions
w3.middleware_onion.add(construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware(account))

# create contract interfaces
token0 = w3.eth.contract(Web3.to_checksum_address("0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"), abi=ERC20_abi)
token1 = w3.eth.contract(Web3.to_checksum_address("0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"), abi=ERC20_abi)
pool = w3.eth.contract(Web3.to_checksum_address("0x11b815efb8f581194ae79006d24e0d814b7697f6"), abi=POOLV3_abi)

# approve pool to recieve WETH
approve_tx = token0.functions.approve(pool.address, w3.to_wei(1, 'ether')).build_transaction({
    'chainId': 1337,
    'gas': 700000,
    })
approve = w3.eth.send_transaction(approve_tx)

# query pool.slot0 for sqrtPrice
slot0 = pool.functions.slot0().call()

# build swap transaction
swap_without_router = pool.functions.swap(
    account.address,
    True,
    w3.to_wei(1, 'ether'),
    slot0[0],
    w3.to_bytes(0x00),
).build_transaction({
    'chainId': 1337,
    'gas': 200000,
    })

#execute tx
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_transaction(swap_without_router)

reciept = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

print(reciept)
```

However this swap fails, if sqrtPriceMax in the transaction input is higher I get the SPL(SquarePriceError) even if it should work as the sqrtPriceMax should be higher than sqrtPrice when swapping token0 for token1. Strangely I do not get the SPL error if I set the sqrtPriceMax below the current sqrtPrice. But in that case anvil will show me an empty error on the transaction.

For now I have no further ideas what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.